# Error when dynamically creating a generic list through reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection, gettype

when i run the program an error message pops up, it says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object from the methodinfo.invoke(data, null). what i want is create a dynamic generic collection in run time, depends on the xml file, it can be `list<classname>`, `dictionary<string, classname>`, `customgenericlist<T>`, etc.

Below are the codes: using list as a test subject.

```
  data = InstantiateGeneric("System.Collections.Generic.List`1", "System.String");
            anobj = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1").MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("System.String"));
            MethodInfo mymethodinfo = anobj.GetMethod("Count");
            Console.WriteLine(mymethodinfo.Invoke(data, null));
```

this is the code to instantiate the said datatype:

```
 public object InstantiateGeneric(string namespaceName_className, string generic_namespaceName_className)
        {
            Type genericType = Type.GetType(namespaceName_className);
            Type[] typeArgs = {Type.GetType(generic_namespaceName_className)};
            Type obj = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(obj);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Count` is a property, not a method:

```
var prop = anobj.GetProperty("Count");
Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(data, null));
```

However, it would be better to cast to the non-generic `IList`:

```
var data = (IList)InstantiateGeneric("System.Collections.Generic.List`1",
                                     "System.String");
Console.WriteLine(data.Count);
```

I also suggest talking in terms of `Type`, not magic strings:

```
var itemType = typeof(string); // from somewhere, perhaps external
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
var data = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
Console.WriteLine(data.Count);
```